# what does $L(s, \pi \times \chi)$ mean in analytic number theory?

Tags: analytic-number-theory, automorphic-forms, l-functions, adeles

Given a Dirichlet character -- a character $\chi: (\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^\times \to \mathbb{C}^\times$ one can define a Dirichlet L-function:

$$ L(s, \chi) = \sum \frac{\chi(n)}{n^s}$$

if $\pi$ is a representation of $\text{GL}(2, \mathbb{A})$ - a very complicated group based on the adèles, $\mathbb{A}$, one can also define an L-function, 
$$ L(s, \pi \times \chi) = \sum \dots $$
If I am not 100% sure of the definition of Adèle, there is discussion on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adele_ring) roughy the product over all completions of $\mathbb{Z}$
$$ \mathbb{A}_\mathbb{Q} \simeq \Big( \hat{\mathbb{Z}} \times \mathbb{R} \Big)\otimes_\mathbb{Z} \mathbb{Q} $$
Presumably the general linear group is the set of $2\times 2$ invertible matrices with elements in this ring:
$$  \text{GL}(2, \mathbb{A}) \stackrel{?}{=} \left\{ \left( \begin{array}{cc} a & b \\ c & d\end{array}\right) : ad -bc = 1 \textbf{ and }a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{A}_\mathbb{Q}\right \} $$

I can even find [textbooks](http://www.math.toronto.edu/arthur/pdf/automorphic-L.pdf) on this standard material, although it is written in rather unforgiving abstract language.

$$ L(s, \pi \times \chi) = \sum \frac{(\pi \times \chi)(n)}{n^s} $$

This is my best guess except I can't think of any examples of $\pi$ and I thought $\pi$ was a function of $2 \times 2$ matrices in  $\text{GL}_2$ rather than integers in $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Automorphic forms are a generalization of modular forms. An intuitive point of view is that if $F(s)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \lambda_f(n)n^{-s}$ is a Dirichlet series with a functional equation $Λ(s)=Q^s\Gamma(\omega s +\mu), Λ(s)=\alpha \overline{\Lambda(1-\overline{s})}$ then $\Gamma(s) F(s)$ is the Mellin transform of $f(\frac{ix}{2\pi})$ where (in most case) $f(\tau)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \lambda_f(n) e^{2i \pi n\tau},Im(\tau)>0$ is a modular form.

Comment: Now when you multiply many such series, you get a Dirichlet series with a functional equation but it has many $\Gamma$ factors [(as in the Selberg and extended Selberg class)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selberg_class), and in that case it is not the Mellin transform of a modular form anymore, but of an automorphic form. Finally, from $F(s),G(s)$ you can look at $F(s)G(s)$ and also at [$F\otimes G(s)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \lambda_f(n)\lambda_g(n)n^{−s}$](http://www.math.umn.edu/~garrett/m/v/basic_rankin_selberg.pdf) a L-function too (when $F,G$ are modular/automorphic)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\pi$ is an automorphic representation. Automorphic representations of $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{Q}})$ correspond to modular forms. In particular, cuspidal automorphic representations of $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{Q}})$ are in a bijective correspondence with the union of the set of Maaß newforms of weight $0$ or $1$ and the set of holomorphic newforms of weight $k \geq 2$.

To read about modular forms, first look perhaps at the Wikipedia articles about them, then perhaps Iwaniec's books on automorphic forms. To see the link between modular forms and automorphic representations, see Goldfeld and Hundley or Bump's books.

Anyway, the key point is that associated to a Maaß newform $f$ or a holomorphic newform $f$ is a multiplicative function $\lambda_f(n)$; these are the eigenvalues of the Hecke operators acting on $f$, and are closely related to the coefficients of the Fourier expansion of $f$.

The $L$ function $L(s,\pi \times \chi)$ is then defined as
\[L(s,\pi \times \chi) = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{\lambda_f(n) \chi(n)}{n^s}.\]
(Actually, this is not quite true - associated to an automorphic representation or a modular form is a conductor $q \geq 1$, and if the conductor $q'$ of the Dirichlet character $\chi$ is not coprime to $q$, then this Dirichlet series needs to be slightly modified.)

In any case, you definitely should not be reading about automorphic representations without first having a very good grasp on modular forms.

Comment: @user1952009, yes, when you multiply together $L$-functions, you get the $L$-function associated to an Eisenstein series (or rather a non-cuspidal automorphic representation). But you must be careful when looking at Rankin-Selberg $L$-functions, because you may need to correct their local $L$-functions at primes dividing both conductors.

Comment: I moved my comments, not supposed to be rigorous but an intuitive point of view when you come from $\zeta(s)$ and Dirichlet L-functions

Comment: In the Dirichlet case I found it written as an [Euler product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_product).
$$ L(s,\chi) = \prod_p \frac{1}{1-\chi(p) p^{-s}} $$
and stunningly, unique factorization still plays a role.  Then I found Artin L-function with a determinant, in these notes of [Arthur](http://www.math.toronto.edu/arthur/pdf/automorphic-L.pdf) - **Lectures on Automorphic L-functions**